# Probability of a duplicate random alphanumeric string with 2x weight on letters

Tags: probability

Ran into this interesting problem at work the other day.

We generate fake email addresses using an random alphanumeric generator to use to register on our site. However, the random alphanumeric generator function we use is case-sensitive (would generate a or A) whereas emails addresses are not (so abc@mail.com is the same as ABC@mail.com). The other day we generated an email address that happened to be duplicate of one we had already generated.

What is the probability of generating a *duplicate* random alphanumeric string of n-length where letters are weighted 2x as compared to a "normal" alphanumeric string (36 different values)?

Hope I was as clear as possible. Let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Comment: The question can be clearer. "What is the probability of generating a random n-length alphanumeric string?" is incomplete. You mean to compare that string with others that have been produced with the same process, and find the probability that the new string is the same as one of the old ones. So explicitly state this, and make it specific (look at $m$ past stings for example).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I forgot to mention the duplicate part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have more or less dealt with the main issues, I'll just bring all information together and give you a sense of the difference you are asking about.

Even though you do not state it clearly, I'll assume you are interested in the probabilities of:

- a new $n$-length string is different to $m$ unique $n$-length strings produced previously
- $m$ $n$-length strings are all different to each other.

I like that you frame the problem as having the same alphabet with different weights for the alphanumeric characters. I believe it's easier to track it this way.

So let's start with the 'normal' case: Producing strings using 26 lower cases letters and 10 digits, all characters chosen randomly and uniformly. Assume you have one $n$-length string already and you produce another one and want to find the probability of them being the same. They'll have to match every character, and the probability of matching one character is $\frac{1}{36}$. So the probability that the two strings match is  $\frac{1}{36^n}$ And the probability that they do not match is  $1-\frac{1}{36^n}$ 
If we compare one string with $m$ unique strings, and ask what is the probability that our string matched with **none** of the $m$, the answer is:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{36^n}\right)^m$$ 
And finally if we have $m$ strings and we want to find the probability that none are the same, this is :
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{36^n}\right)\times \left(1-\frac{2}{36^n}\right)\times  \dots \times \left(1-\frac{m-1}{36^n}\right)  = \frac{\frac{(36^n)!}{(36^n - m)!}}{36^{n\cdot m}}$$

A good approximation of the above (if $m$ is not too large) it to compare all possible pair combinations assuming that each comparison is independent. This gives us the approximation:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{36^n}\right)^{m \choose 2} =\left(1-\frac{1}{36^n}\right)^{m(m-1)/2} $$

Let's look now at the 'weighted' case, where letters are chosen with double the probability of digits. So a lower case letter is chosen with probability $\frac{2}{62}$ and a digit is chosen with probability $\frac{1}{62}$. Let's try the same answers progression. What is the probability that one string matches a previously chosen string? The answer is not so straightforward because it depends on what the previously chosen string is. If it has many digits (which are rarer) it will be more improbable to match. You can attack this problem with two methods (both yielding the same answer of course):

1. find the match probability for an n-length string
2. find the match probability for a single character/symbol string and then raise it to the power of $n$ to get the probability for n-length string.

**Method 1**. Imagine that we have a string with $n$ symbols with $d$ of these symbols being digits. Then the probability that a new n-length string will match is: $$\left(\frac{1}{62}\right)^{d}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{62}\right)^{n-d} = \frac{1}{2^d \cdot 31^n}$$ But now we have this variable $d$ that we want to get rid of. We want the average case.

Let $M_n$ be the event that two n-length strings match and let $P(M_n)$ be the probability of that event. Also let $d$ be the number of digits in the first string. 
$$\begin{align} 
P(M_n) &= P(M_n \cap ((d=0) \cup (d=1) \cup \dots \cup (d=n)) \\
&= P((M_n \cap (d=0)) \cup (M_n \cap (d=1)) \cup \dots \cup (M_n \cap (d=n))\\
&= P(M_n \cap (d=0)) + P(M_n \cap (d=1)) + \dots + P(M_n \cap (d=n)) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n{P(M_n \cap d=i)}  \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n{P(M_n | d=i)\cdot P(d=i)}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n{\frac{1}{2^i \cdot 31^n}\cdot {n \choose i} \left(\frac{10}{62}\right)^i \cdot \left(\frac{52}{62}\right)^{n-i} } \\
&= \frac{1}{31^n} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^n{\frac{1}{2^i}\cdot {n \choose i} \left(\frac{10}{62}\right)^i \cdot \left(\frac{52}{62}\right)^{n-i} }\\
&= \frac{1}{31^n} \cdot \left(\frac{57}{62}\right)^n = \left(\frac{57}{1922}\right)^n
\end{align}$$

**Method 2**. This is easier as it does not require us to find a closed-form formula for the sum appearing in method 1. 
$$\begin{align} 
P(M_1) &= P(M_1 \cap ((d=0) \cup (d=1)) \\
&= P(M_1 \cap (d=0)) + P(M_1 \cap (d=1)) \\
&= \frac{2}{62}\cdot \frac{52}{62} + \frac{1}{62}\cdot \frac{10}{62} = \frac{57}{1922}
\end{align}$$
And thus:
$$P(M_n) = (P(M_1))^n = \left(\frac{57}{1922}\right)^n$$

The rest of the analysis is the same is in the 'normal' case. So if we compare one string with $m$ unique strings, and ask what is the probability that our string matched with **none** of the $m$, the answer is:
$$\left(1-\left(\frac{57}{1922}\right)^n\right)^m$$

And finally if we have $m$ strings and we want to find the probability that none are the same, this is:
$$\left(1-\left(\frac{57}{1922}\right)^n\right)\times \left(1-2\times \left(\frac{57}{1922}\right)^n\right)\times  \dots \times \left(1-(m-1)\times \left(\frac{57}{1922}\right)^n\right) $$

As before, a good approximation is:
$$\left(1-\left(\frac{57}{1922}\right)^n\right)^{m \choose 2} =\left(1-\left(\frac{57}{1922}\right)^n\right)^{m(m-1)/2}$$

Let's compute some values to get a sense of the difference between the 'normal' and 'weighted' cases. Let's consider strings of $n=5$ symbols length. And let's compute the **probability that $m$ such strings are all different**, for different values of $m$.

$$
\begin{array}{r|cc}
m & \text{Normal} & \text{Weighted} \\
\hline
1,000 & 0.992 & 0.989  \\
5,000 & 0.813 & 0.751  \\
10,000 & 0.437 & 0.318 \\
15,000 & 0.156 & 0.076 \\
20,000 & 0.037 & 0.010
\end{array}
$$

As we expected it is less probable to have $m$ unique strings with the weighted case, or in other words, it's more probable to get "collisions" when generating strings with the weighted case. As you can see from the numerical examples, there are certain ranges of values for $n$ and $m$ that make this difference pronounced. Outside these ranges the probability of collisions will either be too low (close to $0$) or too high (close to $1$) and will not make much practical difference if you are using the normal or weighted case.

Comment: To get the closed form formula for the sum in method 1, I used the help of Wolfram Alpha: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%7Bk%3D0..n%7D((1%2F2%5Ek)*+(n+choose+k)*+(p)%5Ek*(1-p)%5E(n-k)))

Comment: The formula above taking the product of $mC2$ comparisons is an approximation. It assumes all comparisons are independent. It is a very good approximation, however!

Comment: @ScottBurns yes, thank you. I edited my answer to include the exact formula and refer to the approximation too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the start of an answer, dealing with the probability that two randomly generated strings match when you ignore case. You'll need this information when you answer @Thanassis comment to clarify the context.

The best way to tackle a problem like this is to look at small cases. Suppose first that you have only alphabetic strings, that $n=1$ and that the first string is "a". Then the chance that the second one letter string matches "a" is $2/52 = 1/26$ since both "a" and "A" do the job.

The calculation for alphanumerics is a little more complicated. If the initial string is alpha (of length 1) then the probability of a match is $2/(52+10) = 1/31$. If the string is numeric then the probability is just $1/62$.

So for a string of length $n = a + b$ where $a$ is the number of letters and $b$ the number of numbers the probability of a match is
$$
\frac{1}{31^a 62^b} = \frac{1}{2^b 31^n} .
$$
Next steps would be finding the probabilities of $a$ and $b$ given $n$ (binomial coefficients here), then taking into account the number of previously generated strings you might match.

Unless you generate lots of these fake emails the chance of a duplicate is pretty small: $31^{-6}$ is about one in a billion.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of matching $n$ characters is the probability of matching each character in turn. So calculate the probability of matching one character and then raise to the power $n$.

Let's say that the 2 strings generated are P and Q and let P[1] be the 1st character of P.

Then

Pr(P[1]=Q[1]) =

Pr((P[1]=Q[1]) AND (P[1] is alphabetic)) + Pr((P[1]=Q[1]) AND (P[1] is numeric))

Pr(P[1] is alphabetic) = 52/62 = 26/31, and we match with probability 2/62, so the first part of the sum is 26/961.

Pr(P[1] is numeric) = 10/62 = 5/31, and we match with probability 1/62, so the second part of the sum is 5/1922.

Overall the probability of a match is 57/1922, and So for an $n$-character string, the probability is $(57/1922)^n$

But this isn't really solving your problem. It's only addressing a single pair of strings. You were surprised to get a repeat, but ask yourself how many strings you had previously generated. Any one of those could have provided the match!

So a better approach would be to ask 'what is the probability I got a repeat having generated $N$ strings of length $n$?'

Or, equivalently, 'what is the probability I got no repeats having generated $N$ strings of length $n$?'

The second question turns out easier to answer, but it's still rather tricky, requiring a large amount of multinomial computation.

However, using the calculation above, we can at least calaculate the expected number of repeats. If we have $N$ strings, we have $NC2$ = $N(N-1)/2$ comparisons.

Therefore the expected number of repeated pairs is

$(57/1922)^n N(N-1)/2$